# Что произойдет с диском со старой виндой при установке нового диска с новой виндой?

Tags: windows, ssd

такая ситуация - есть в компе один диск, разделенный на три других(один "C" и два виртуальных). На "C" стоит семерка. Купил себе новый ssd, хочу поставить на него новую десятку. Собственно сам вопрос - что произойдет с первым диском и его виртуальными дисками, если я просто вставлю ssd с новой виндой и в биосе поставлю его на первоначальный запуск? Не удалится ли что-то с диска "C"?
Если что-то не так или тут такие вопросы не задают, прошу прощения, никогда не пользовался такого рода сайтами.

Comment: Не удалится (главное сами не накосячьте где-нибудь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что если вы не будете производить никаких манипуляций с первым SSD, кроме понижения приоритета его загрузки, то ничего не должно произойти, так как данные на нем изолированы от второго SSD, но будьте внимательны при настройке разделов на этапе установке Windows, чтобы случайно не форматировать данные на первом носителе, решение принимать вам, но не будет лишним создать резервные копии всех важных файлов, желаю удачи!